# System of symmetric equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I was working on writing some problems for a contest, and I wrote the following system of equations:

\begin{align*}
x^2+yz&=259,\\
y^2+zx&=217,\\
z^2+xy&=203.
\end{align*}

Of course, this was written "backwards." I was interested in this system, chose a solution $(x,y,z)$, and then plugged in the values to create the problem.

Unfortunately, I can't find a solution that goes from this system to the ordered triple $(x,y,z)$. The first thing I tried was subtracting the equations in pairs and factoring to get the new system

\begin{align*}
(x-y)(x+y-z)&=42,\\
(y-z)(y+z-x)&=14,\\
(z-x)(z+x-y)&=56.\\
\end{align*}

Although this system seems like it should be easier to work with, I can't make any progress, and am beginning to doubt if its even an improvement on the original. Adding all 3 equations and multiplying by 2 gives

$$(x+y)^2+(y+z)^2+(z+x)^2=1358,$$

which also seems useful, but I am still unable to use to solve the system.

Also, multiplying each equation by $x$, $y$, or $z$ and summing gives

$$x^3+y^3+z^3+3xyz=259x+217y+203z,$$

which might be promising since the polynomial $x^2+y^3+z^3-3xyz$ factors nicely.

Since the system is relatively "nice" and symmetric, I was expecting to find a simple solution, and might just be missing something obvious. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: With Gröbner bases? Or, as  these are equations of hyperboloids, find a parametrisation of one of them and use it  to obtain the solutions.

Comment: I don't see why it be necessary that they are integers? The system $x^2+xy=5$, $y^2+xy=10$ has non-integral solutions, and is a fine contest problem.

Comment: This problem seems to be a nightmare ! It probably shows $8$ solutions, reduced to $4$ by symetry (changing simultaneously  $x$ to $-x$, $y$ to $-y$, $z$ to $-z$).

Comment: If you had $x^2-yz, ...$ etc. as your system, a nice simple solution seems evident.

Comment: Macavity, I haven't analyzed that version in much detail, but could you give a sketch of the "simple solution" ?

Comment: Observing that the gcd of $259, 217$, and $203$ is $7$, we can set $x' = \sqrt 7x, y' = \sqrt 7y$, and $z' = \sqrt 7z$. The resulting system has integer solutions which are easy enough to find.

Comment: That being said, this observation came after having seen the solution thanks to Wolfram Alpha...